# ADO.Net DataType of column of DataTable issue

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net, datatable, types

My question is how to assign the DataType value for columns of special SQL Types like, uniqueidentifier/nvarchar/datetime/varbinary(max) -- I did not find a mapping between .NET data type and such 4 types of SQL column data type?

Here is a sample, which shows we need to assign the DataType (this sample maps .NET type to SQL column data type) of each column of the DataTable.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about the DataType property on the DataColumn class, this is how you would map the types:

- uniqueidentifier - Guid
- nvarchar - String
- datetime - DateTime
- varbinary(max) - byte[]

You can find the full list of mappings here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx

Comment: Cool, casperOne! Are there any full mapping tables for any related .Net type for SQL Data type?

Comment: @George2 - This is what you want: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You might also want to read this msdn page:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.datatype.aspx

Comment: But there is no mapping, just mentioned supported .Net data types for DataType property on the DataColumn class. Are there any documents covering a full mapping table for any related .Net type for SQL Data type?

Comment: Are there any full mapping tables for any related .Net type for SQL Data type?